# Uisng Nginx Ingress to implement Blue-Green Deployment between two AKS clusters

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, azure-dns

please i wanted to find out if it is possible to implement a blue-green deployment for my application on separate AKS clusters using ***nginx ingress controller***.
I have the current application (blue) running on one AKS cluster and i have a new AKS cluster (Green, with a new k8s version) where i want to migrate my workloads to.
Is it possible to implement the blue-green deployment strategy between these 2 AKS clusters using ***nginx ingress controller***? If so, please can someone give me a suggestion on how this can be implemented? Thank you

Comment: I am pretty sure you'll at the least need a service mesh for this. A service mesh like linkerd or istio can span multiple clusters, whereas nginx ingress is local to a single cluster. I would take a look at support for k8s b/g deployment tools such as [flagger](https://flagger.app/) or [argocd rollouts](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/).

Comment: you can check flagger https://docs.flagger.app/tutorials/linkerd-progressive-delivery

Comment: why use two clusters when you can use two namespaces within same cluster?

Comment: @YK1 One of the clusters is running an older version of k8s. Hence the reason for the new cluster with the new k8s version. I did not want to use the option of upgrading my control plane k8s version to the new k8s version and then upgrading the k8s version of the worker nodes

Comment: If you want to split traffic between clusters, you need a load balancer which is deployed outside the clusters. An ingress controller resides inside the cluster so cannot split traffic between two clusters.